Can't make WebSocket connection into docker container (minimal example)
I'm unable to make a WebSocket connection into a docker container that's running a WebSocket server.  Other protocols seem to connect fine, just not Websocket.
(E.g. with running nats-server in a container configured to serve NATS on port 422 and ws on port 8080, running docker run -p 4222:422 -p 8080:8080 ..., I can connect a nats client to nats://localhost:4222 but attempting to connect a web socket client to ws://localhost:127.0.0.1 fails with an unhelpful message.)
I've reduced down to the most minimal example I can come up with, using websocat serving on port 9000.  Here's the Dockerfile:
FROM alpine:3.20
RUN apk add websocat
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["websocat", "-v", "-v", "-v", "-s", "9000", "-P", "Working"]

I can build and run a container using -p 9000:9000, and see that websocat is awaiting connections:
$ docker build . --tag websocat
[...output suppressed...]
 => => unpacking to docker.io/library/websocat:latest  
$ docker run -p 9000:9000 websocat
Listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9000/
[DEBUG websocat::lints] Substituting StdioClass with AsyncStdioClass at the right
[INFO  websocat::lints] Auto-inserting the line mode
[DEBUG websocat] Done third phase of interpreting options.
[DEBUG websocat] Done fourth phase of interpreting options.
[DEBUG websocat] Preparation done. Now actually starting.
[DEBUG websocat::sessionserve] Serving Message2Line(WsServer(TcpListen(127.0.0.1:9000))) to BroadcastReuser(Line2Message(AsyncStdio)) with Options { websocket_text_mode: true, websocket_protocol: None, websocket_reply_protocol: None, udp_oneshot_mode: false, udp_broadcast: false, udp_multicast_loop: false, udp_ttl: None, udp_join_multicast_addr: [], udp_join_multicast_iface_v4: [], udp_join_multicast_iface_v6: [], udp_reuseaddr: false, unidirectional: false, unidirectional_reverse: false, max_messages: None, max_messages_rev: None, exit_on_eof: true, oneshot: false, unlink_unix_socket: false, unix_socket_accept_from_fd: false, exec_args: [], ws_c_uri: "ws://0.0.0.0/", linemode_strip_newlines: false, linemode_strict: false, origin: None, custom_headers: [], custom_reply_headers: [], websocket_version: None, websocket_dont_close: false, websocket_ignore_zeromsg: false, one_message: false, no_auto_linemode: false, buffer_size: 65536, broadcast_queue_len: 16, read_debt_handling: Warn, linemode_zero_terminated: false, restrict_uri: None, serve_static_files: [], exec_set_env: false, no_exit_on_zeromsg: false, reuser_send_zero_msg_on_disconnect: false, process_zero_sighup: false, process_exit_sighup: false, process_exit_on_disconnect: false, socks_destination: None, auto_socks5: None, socks5_bind_script: None, tls_domain: None, tls_insecure: false, headers_to_env: [], max_parallel_conns: None, ws_ping_interval: None, ws_ping_timeout: None, request_uri: None, request_method: None, request_headers: [], autoreconnect_delay_millis: 20, ws_text_prefix: None, ws_binary_prefix: None, ws_binary_base64: false, ws_text_base64: false, close_status_code: None, close_reason: None, asyncstdio: true, foreachmsg_wait_reads: false, announce_listens: false, timestamp_monotonic: false, print_ping_rtts: false, byte_to_exit_on: 28, max_ws_message_length: 209715200, max_ws_frame_length: 104857600, preamble: [], preamble_reverse: ["Working"], compress_deflate: false, compress_zlib: false, compress_gzip: false, uncompress_deflate: false, uncompress_zlib: false, uncompress_gzip: false, jsonrpc_omit_jsonrpc: false, inhibit_pongs: None, max_sent_pings: None, lengthprefixed_header_bytes: 4, lengthprefixed_little_endian: false, lengthprefixed_skip_read_direction: false, lengthprefixed_skip_write_direction: false }
[DEBUG websocat::net_peer] Listening TCP socket

Verifying the port mapping:
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS             PORTS                    NAMES
4325c321f2c3   websocat   "websocat -v -v -v -…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp   great_curran

But then trying to connect fails:
$ websocat -v -v -v ws://127.0.0.1:9000
[INFO  websocat::lints] Auto-inserting the line mode
[DEBUG websocat] Done third phase of interpreting options.
[DEBUG websocat] Done fourth phase of interpreting options.
[DEBUG websocat] Preparation done. Now actually starting.
[DEBUG websocat::sessionserve] Serving Line2Message(ThreadedStdio) to Message2Line(WsClient("ws://127.0.0.1:9000/")) with Options { websocket_text_mode: true, websocket_protocol: None, websocket_reply_protocol: None, udp_oneshot_mode: false, udp_broadcast: false, udp_multicast_loop: false, udp_ttl: None, udp_join_multicast_addr: [], udp_join_multicast_iface_v4: [], udp_join_multicast_iface_v6: [], udp_reuseaddr: false, unidirectional: false, unidirectional_reverse: false, max_messages: None, max_messages_rev: None, exit_on_eof: false, oneshot: false, unlink_unix_socket: false, unix_socket_accept_from_fd: false, exec_args: [], ws_c_uri: "ws://0.0.0.0/", linemode_strip_newlines: false, linemode_strict: false, origin: None, custom_headers: [], custom_reply_headers: [], websocket_version: None, websocket_dont_close: false, websocket_ignore_zeromsg: false, one_message: false, no_auto_linemode: false, buffer_size: 65536, broadcast_queue_len: 16, read_debt_handling: Warn, linemode_zero_terminated: false, restrict_uri: None, serve_static_files: [], exec_set_env: false, no_exit_on_zeromsg: false, reuser_send_zero_msg_on_disconnect: false, process_zero_sighup: false, process_exit_sighup: false, process_exit_on_disconnect: false, socks_destination: None, auto_socks5: None, socks5_bind_script: None, socks5_user_pass: None, tls_domain: None, tls_insecure: false, headers_to_env: [], max_parallel_conns: None, ws_ping_interval: None, ws_ping_timeout: None, request_uri: None, request_method: None, request_headers: [], autoreconnect_delay_millis: 20, ws_text_prefix: None, ws_binary_prefix: None, ws_binary_base64: false, ws_text_base64: false, close_status_code: None, close_reason: None, asyncstdio: false, foreachmsg_wait_reads: false, announce_listens: false, timestamp_monotonic: false, print_ping_rtts: false, byte_to_exit_on: 28, max_ws_message_length: 209715200, max_ws_frame_length: 104857600, preamble: [], preamble_reverse: [], compress_deflate: false, compress_zlib: false, compress_gzip: false, uncompress_deflate: false, uncompress_zlib: false, uncompress_gzip: false, jsonrpc_omit_jsonrpc: false, inhibit_pongs: None, max_sent_pings: None, lengthprefixed_header_bytes: 4, lengthprefixed_little_endian: false, lengthprefixed_skip_read_direction: false, lengthprefixed_skip_write_direction: false }
[INFO  websocat::stdio_threaded_peer] get_stdio_peer (threaded)
[DEBUG websocat::sessionserve] Underlying connection established
[INFO  websocat::ws_client_peer] get_ws_client_peer
[INFO  websocat::net_peer] Connected to TCP 127.0.0.1:9000
websocat: WebSocketError: WebSocket protocol error
websocat: error running

Similarly, attempting to connect via curl shows an empty response:
$ curl -v -i -N -H "Connection: Upgrade" -H "Upgrade: websocket" -H "Host: 127.0.0.1:9000" -H "Origin: http://127.0.0.1" http://127.0.0.1:9000
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:9000...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 9000
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:9000
> User-Agent: curl/8.7.1
> Accept: */*
> Connection: Upgrade
> Upgrade: websocket
> Origin: http://127.0.0.1
>
* Request completely sent off
* Empty reply from server
* Closing connection
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

In both cases, the websocat server doesn't log any attempted connection.
Confirming that the server is really working, making a connection within the running container works fine:
$ docker exec 4325c321f2c3 websocat -v ws://127.0.0.1:9000/
[INFO  websocat::lints] Auto-inserting the line mode
[INFO  websocat::ws_client_peer] get_ws_client_peer
[INFO  websocat::net_peer] Connected to TCP 127.0.0.1:9000
[INFO  websocat::ws_client_peer] Connected to ws
[INFO  websocat::sessionserve] Forward finished
Working
[INFO  websocat::ws_peer] incoming None
[INFO  websocat::sessionserve] Reverse finished
[INFO  websocat::sessionserve] Both directions finished

and the server of course logs the connection:
[INFO  websocat::net_peer] Incoming TCP connection from Some(127.0.0.1:46268)
[DEBUG websocat::sessionserve] Underlying connection established
[INFO  websocat::sessionserve] Serving 1 ongoing connections
[INFO  websocat::ws_server_peer] Incoming connection to websocket: /
[...etc...]

I've tried this both on:

MacOS 15.1.1 (Intel), docker 27.3.1
Ubuntu 24.04, docker 27.4.0

Same failure for both.
Is there something I'm missing...?

Anything that says "listening on 127.0.0.1" will be unreachable from outside its own container; also see Docker app server ip address 127.0.0.1 difference of 0.0.0.0 ip.  It looks like your listener option might need to be -s 0.0.0.0:9000.

Aha! That fixes it, thanks!  Make this into an answer instead of a comment and I'll accept it.
